# Passing data backwards

Tags: ios, swift, database, parameter-passing

Basically, I have two ViewController in my application. The FirstViewController contains a UITextField, UILabel and a UITextView. When the user execute a LongPressGesture over the UITextView the SecondViewController pops-up to display a table with selections for the user to select one of them. And when the user touch anywhere on the screen apart from the table displayed in the piped-up SecondViewController the SecondViewController disappears.

What I want to achieve, is as soon as the SecondViewController disappears I want a variable to be passed from the SecondViewController to the FirstViewController specifically into the UITextField.

The way I am trying to make this work is as follow:

(1) I defined a Protocol inside the SecondViewController as below:

```
import UIKit

protocol MyProtocol {

    func setResultOfBusinessLogic(valueSent: String) // valueSent represents the Variable that we will send from the SecondViewController to the FirstViewController.

}
```

(2) I defined a variable inside the SecondViewController, which will holds the value to be passed into the FirstViewController, when the pop-up window for the SecondViewController disappears:

```
class IndicativeDesignWorkingLifeVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var delegate:MyProtocol? // We will also create a variable of type MyProtocol which will be accessed from FirstViewController.

}
```

(3) Next, in the SecondViewController underneath the ViewWillDisappear function, I performed the below logic, which will needs to be performed and the result of it will send as an argument to the setResultOfBusinessLogic function defined in bullet-point (1):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    // Next, we will add some business logic that needs to be performed inside of viewWillAppear function and the result of it will be sent as an argument to setResultOfBusinessLogic function.

    let firstName = "Sergey"

    let lastName = "Kargopolov"

    let fullName = firstName + " " + lastName


    delegate?.setResultOfBusinessLogic(valueSent: fullName)

}
```

(4)I made the FirstViewController conforms to the Protocol I created previously in the SecondViewController as below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, MyProtocol {

}
```

(5) I created a Variable inside the FirstViewController, which will hold the value passed from the SecondViewController as below:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, MyProtocol {

var valueSentFromSecondViewController:String?

    }
```

(6) I added the below function towards the end of the FirstViewController to make sure that the FirstViewController conforms to the Protocol I created earlier on inside the SecondViewController:

```
func setResultOfBusinessLogic(valueSent: String) {

    if valueSentFromSecondViewController == valueSent {

        testTextField.text = valueSentFromSecondViewController

    }
}
```

(7) Lastly, I added the below code underneath the function inside the FirstViewController, which instantiate the SecondViewController as a pop-over window when a LongPressGesture is detected inside the UITextView:

```
func longpressGestureTriggeredForIndicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView (gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }

            let popController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IndicativeDesignWorkingLifeVC")

            let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IndicativeDesignWorkingLifeVC") as! IndicativeDesignWorkingLifeVC

            secondViewController.delegate = self

            popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
            popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up

            popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self

            popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView!)

            popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: (indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView.contentSize.width)/2 , y: (indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView.contentSize.height), width: 0, height: 0) // this line of code controls the location of the popover arrow head. In terms of its horizontal as well as vertical position from where it is going to popup, in this case from the UITextView object.

                self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

However, with all the above when the popped-over SecondViewController I do not see the parameter from the SecondViewController (i.e., fullName) getting displayed inside the UITextField in the FirstViewController.

Could anyone please guide me on what did I do wrong? why it is not working? Am I missing something here?

Thanks,
Shadi.

Comment: You are close, but you have a couple of problems. Your second view controller should call the delegate method from `viewWillDisappear`, not `viewWillAppear` and your first view controllers `viewWillAppear` won't be called when a popover closes, since it was already visible.  You should update the UI directly in the `setResultOfBusinessLogic` delegate method

Comment: Thanks Paul for your reply, however, since I am new to coding could you please guide me on how I can update the UI from setResultOfBusinessLogic delegate?

Comment: Just update the the `text` property of your label or whatever in the delegate method.

Comment: Hi Paul, I updated my above code as below: (1) I kept everything that I previously mentioned in the SecondViewController the same apart from moving what I used to have previously underneath the ViewWillAppear function to ViewWillDisappear function as below. (2) I deleted what I previously had underneath the ViewWillAppear function in the FirstViewController. (3) I deleted what I previously had underneath the function which gets executed when a LongPressGesture is detected in the UITextView in the FirstViewController. (4) I made the following changes to the protocol function

Comment: in the FirstViewController as below:        func setResultOfBusinessLogic(valueSent: String) {
        
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IndicativeDesignWorkingLifeVC") as! IndicativeDesignWorkingLifeVC
                
        secondViewController.delegate = self
        
        self.valueSentFromSecondViewController = valueSent

        if let valueToDisplay = valueSentFromSecondViewController {
            
            testTextField.text = valueToDisplay
            
        }

Comment: However, I cannot still get it to work? any further suggestion on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Paul, I updated my code to reflect the changes I made as per your recommendation, in case my previous explanation was not clear.